# VHDL division, numerator =1

Tags: vhdl

what about if the numerator = 1 in division using VHDL ?
e.g.

```
y=1/x;
```

what is the most efficient way to implement this (inverse )?

Comment: What are the types involved?

Comment: To answer your question you'd have to specify the maximum latency, the target technology, etc., i.e., it can't be answerd in general. But with float your choice is rather limited by your target (simulation/FPGA/ASIC) and the libraries supplied, that is if you don't want to do it yourself.
One FPGA targeted approach that can always be considered is having a lookup table and then do some interpolation.

Comment: What is the required precision? Do you have a minimum number of decimal places, or a fixed number of storage bits? How many clock cycles can you spend in the calculation?

Comment: Define "efficient" - in terms of logic area, power, throughput, latency, development time...?

Comment: thanks for reply,,target is FPGA, 16 bit for storage, 4 places for decimal, no clock cycles assigned ( as small as possible) and I mean efficient in area.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "4 places for decimal"? 4 places in base 10, or base 2? Or 4 bits representing the exponent?

Is the value truly floating point, or can it be represented as fixed point?

The most efficient way to implement division in hardware is to not do it at all. Take a look at a larger part of your design, think a little outside the box, and see if there is a way to do it without division.
Counters can sometimes replace division and multiplication. For example.

Answer (score 0):

You have clarified that you are working with floating point numbers.

It all depends on what libraries you have available. If you need to implement a floating point reciprocal from scratch in VHDL, using just numeric_std, this will be a significant effort. Just for illustration: you'd probably split up the exponent and mantissa, calculate the exponent by inverting the value, and implement the mantissa with a piecewise interpolation. Another approach that may require less research but other working floating point components is to do Newton-Raphson iteration on an initial crude estimate.

If you have no specific interest in doing this yourself
I recommend looking at http://flopoco.gforge.inria.fr/. Flopoco is a generator that produces working VHDL code for a large range of floating point operations. If you don't have Linux, use a virtual machine to run it. It may not produce fully IEEE-754 compliant designs, but I've experimented with it a bit and it looks very useful!